# Oozie Hive Action Using -i init script

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

How can I run an Oozie Hive or Hive2 Action with init scripts?

In the CLI this can be usually done via the `-i init.hive` argument; however when using this in an Oozie Action via `<argument>-i init.hive</argument>` the workflow stops with an error.

I linked the init.hive file with the `<file>init.hive#init.hive</file>` property and it is available in the local appcache directory.

```
$ ll appcache/application_1480609892100_0274/container_e55_1480609892100_0274_01_000001/ | grep init
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    42 Jan 12 12:24 init.hive -> /hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/519/init.hive
```

The error (in the local appcache) is the following

```
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 1.2.1000.2.4.0.0-169)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1000.2.4.0.0-169)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Running init script  init.hive
  init.hive (No such file or directory)
```

The hive2 action looks like this (the complete workflow can be found on Github https://github.com/chaosmail/oozie-bugs/tree/master/simple-hive-init/simple-hive-init-wf)

```
<action name="test-action">
<hive2 xmlns="uri:oozie:hive2-action:0.1">
  <jdbc-url>${jdbcURL}</jdbc-url>
  <script>query.hive</script>
  <argument>-i init.hive</argument>
  <file>init.hive#init.hive</file>
</hive2>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

Edit 1: added workflow action

Comment: Can you provide the complete workflow/action used here? Where have you stored the init.hive file?

Comment: The init.hive file is stored in the same dir as the workflow.xml

Comment: Interestingly, running a shell action and outputting `pwd` it matches with the `appcache/application_1480609892100_0274/container_e55_1480609892100_0274_01_000001` directory. It seems that the beeline client might not be started in the same local container directory - otherwise it should find the init.hive file

Comment: Interestingly, you download `init.hive` from HDFS to your container CWD, but you don't download `query.hive`, so your action would fail anyway...

Comment: For the record, with Hive 2.2+ you can specify the init script directly inside the URL https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5867

Comment: The Oozie documentation https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_Hive2ActionExtension.html states that you may have **multiple** `<argument>` tags, and your logs show a leading space before the script name (the space following `-i`??) >> consider trying `<argument>-i</argument><argument>init.hive</argument>`

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter `query.hive` gets downloaded to local appcache because it is passed in the script tag.

Comment: *"...gets downloaded ... because it is passed in the script tag"* -- either it's a new Oozie feature that I don't know of, or it's not the real reason. I would rather bet on the fact that *any* file present in the Workflow dir gets downloaded as if it was in a `<file>` tag, just as any JAR present in the `lib` sub-directory gets downloaded and added to CLASSPATH.

Comment: I am refering to the Oozie source code where paths passed in the <script> tag get cached separately. Thats why also a relativ path would work in the <script> tag.  https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/Hive2ActionExecutor.java#L92

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter `<argument>-i</argument><argument>init.hive</argument>` or `<argument>-iinit.hive</argument>` did the trick, thanks for the help. If you paste your comment into an answer I can accept it. Best, Christoph

Comment: Here is a similar problem where the password file is passed via `<argument>-wpassfile</argument>` https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/3251/running-hive-in-oozie-with-hive2action-and-passwor.html

Comment: I have put both scripts (my_script and init script) in workflow directory but only my_script got copied to nm local directory. So i have used the <file> tag to copy it to node local directory and it worked. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: <script>maprfs:///tmp/jobs/myscript.hql</script> 
<argument>-i</argument>
<argument>init.hql</argument>
<file>maprfs:///tmp/jobs/init.hql#init.hql</file>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Recap of the comments thread above, plus some extra stuff in retrospect]*

The Oozie documentation states that you may have multiple `<argument>` elements in your Action, which hints that the arguments must be provided separately.
*In retrospect, it makes sense -- on a command line, it's the* shell *that would parse the list of arguments into an* `args[]` *array for the Java executable, but Oozie is not a shell interpreter...*

And experience shows that Beeline accepts two syntax variants for its command-line args...

- `-xValue` (one arg) means option `-x` with associated `Value`
- `-x` followed by `Value` (two args) means the same thing

---

So you have two correct ways to pass command-line arguments to Beeline via Oozie:

- `<argument>-xValue</argument>`
- `<argument>-x</argument> <argument>Value</argument>`

On the other hand, `<argument>-x Value</argument>` would fail, because in single-arg syntax, Beeline considers that the separator space should be part of the value...!